# How to get value of all textView inside Listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get all the values of a TextView and an EditText inside a ListView but I am having a weird issue. Here is my sample code, I removed the EditText to keep it simple:

```
 lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.person_details_lv);
        Integer x = lv.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < lv.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
            View viewRow = lv.getChildAt(i);
            //this next condition get the index of the view visible only
         if (viewRow != null) {
            TextView NameEditText = (TextView) viewRow.findViewById(R.id.detail_name);
            Log.d("hello", "Anything detected onscreen:" + NameEditText.getText().toString() + ");
        }}
```

The issue is that it only return the View visible on screen. However, the `getCount` counts everything. As a results, I am getting this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I added this  condition:  `if (viewRow != null)` to remove the error but it keeps showing only the View visible on screen. When I scroll the listView, the results change as well. What I want to do is to get the value of the TextViewe in the ListView whether seen onscreen or not.

Comment: retrieve values from the list you are using

Comment: Why don't you get the elements out of the Adapter?

Comment: please show how you set up the adapter - is there some List containing all the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should implement this method:

```
 public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition
                + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition) {
            return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
            return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
    }
```

And then call this method by remplacing your:

```
View viewRow = lv.getChildAt(i);
```

with:

```
viewRow= getViewByPosition(i, lv);
```

And  that's it! you don't need to change the rest. Just remove this `if (viewRow != null)` . I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Becuase not all the views in your listview items are of type TextView so when you cast them som of them are null. (Casting views other than TextView to TextView makes null object)

After casting just check if its not null its a TextView if its null just skip it .

ADD THE NULL CONDITION AFTER CASTING !

Answer (score -1):

You have to store your Listview item in List‹› you passed to adapter. You have to store value of EditText when OnTextChanged is called. TextView value already available in your List.